# Does anyone know how to generate on the fly page that contain iframe of specific site That his address appears after the main site address?

Tags: iframe

Does anyone know how to generate on the fly page that contain iframe of specific site That his address appears after the main site address ?

SAMPLE

http://news.fresh.co.il/shownews.php?link=http://www.cnn.com

Answer (score 2):

Check this: [How does the DiggBar work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736730/how-does-the-diggbar-work)
you can replace `src="http://url.to/page"` with `src="<? echo $_GET['link']?>;"`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to just use HTML frames and have one frame's source be the contents of $_GET['link'], no?